# Google Drive Spreadsheet Keys

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Have multiple references to other google drive spreadsheets using importrange with spreadsheet key.  For some reason the spreadsheet keys appear to have changed, but I can find no way to prevent this happening or to make my importrange statements update automatically.

This leaves me having to search out and open all the referenced spreadsheets, copy the new key and paste it into every importarange statement to correct it.

Does any one know a way around this or how to protect against it.  Also does any one know why the spreadsheet keys may have changed?

Also there are some it is not clear from the context, which spreadsheet it is referring to.  Does any one know how i might find that out seeing as the key has changed.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the Spreadsheet key has been changed is that the sheets are updated to new sheets. You can check that by checking the starting character value of the Spreadsheet key. If the value is 0, it is an old sheet and if it is 1, it is a new sheet.

The only way you can get the changed sheet from the old key is finding the sheet in drive by spreadsheet key and it will give you the new sheet. May be you can also add the old key in the sheet url and it will redirect to the actual sheet with new key.

Hope that helps!